# Python regex issue with optional substring in between

Tags: python, regex

Been bashing my head on this since 2 days. I'm trying to match a packet content with regex API:

```
packet_re = (r'.*RADIUS.*\s*Accounting(\s|-)Request.*(Framed(\s|-)IP(\s|-)Address.*Attribute.*Value: (?P<client_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))?.*(Username|User-Name)(\s|-)Attribute.*Value:\s*(?P<username>\S+).*')

packet1 = """
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 35592, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 213)
    10.10.10.1.41860 > 10.10.10.3.1813: [udp sum ok] RADIUS, length: 185
    Accounting-Request (4), id: 0x0a, Authenticator: 41b3b548c4b7f65fe810544995620308
      Framed-IP-Address Attribute (8), length: 6, Value: 10.10.10.11
        0x0000:  0a0a 0a0b
      User-Name Attribute (1), length: 14, Value: 005056969256
        0x0000:  3030 3530 3536 3936 3932 3536
"""
result = search(packet_re, packet1, DOTALL)
```

The regex matches, but it fails to capture `Framed-IP-Address Attribute`, `client_ip=10.10.10.11`. The thing is `Framed-IP-Address Attribute` can or cannot come in the packet. Hence the pattern is enclosed in another capture group ending with `?` meaning 0 or 1 occurrence.

I should be able to ignore it when it doesn't come. Hence packet content can also be:

```
packet2 = """
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60162, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 163)
    20.20.20.1.54035 > 20.20.20.2.1813: [udp sum ok] RADIUS, length: 135
    Accounting-Request (4), id: 0x01, Authenticator: 219b694bcff639221fa29940e8d2a4b2
      User-Name Attribute (1), length: 14, Value: 005056962f54
        0x0000:  3030 3530 3536 3936 3266 3534
"""
```

The regex should ignore Framed-IP-Address in this case. It does ignore but it doesn't capture when it does come.

Comment: Looks like you may use `RADIUS.*?Accounting[\s-]Request(?:.*?(Framed[\s-]IP[\s-]Address.*?Attribute(?:.*?Value: (?P<client_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))?))?.*User-?[nN]ame[\s-]Attribute.*?Value:\s*(?P<username>\S+)` - https://regex101.com/r/HGxPzW/1. You do not need `.*` at the start and end, because even if you need the whole string to be present in the match, you can use `result.string` to obtain it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. There's a lot to learn with your answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
RADIUS.*?Accounting[\s-]Request(?:.*?(Framed[\s-]IP[\s-]Address.*?Attribute(?:.*?Value: (?P<client_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))?))?.*User-?[nN]ame[\s-]Attribute.*?Value:\s*(?P<username>\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HGxPzW/1).

Note I removed `.*` on both ends of the pattern as you are using `re.search` that does not require matching at the start of string like `re.match`, and the `MatchData` object contains [`.string` property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.string) that you can access to obtain the whole input string.

*Details*

- `RADIUS` - a word
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `Accounting` - a word
- `[\s-]` - a whitespace or hyphen
- `Request` - a word
- `(?:.*?` - start of an optional non-capturing group: any zero or more chars as few as possible, then...

  - `(Framed[\s-]IP[\s-]Address.*?Attribute` - Group 1: `Framed` + a whitespace or a hyphen + `IP` + whitespace/hyphen + `Address` + any zero or more chars as few as possible + `Attribute`

    - `(?:.*?Value: (?P<client_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching any zero or more chars as few as possible + `Value:`  + Group "client_ip": four one or more digit matching patterns separated with a literal dot
  - `)` - end of the Group 1
- `)?` - end of the outer non-capturing group
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `User-?[nN]ame`  - `Username`, `UserName` or `User-name`/`User-Name`
- `[\s-]` - whitespace or hyphen
- `Attribute` - a word
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `Value:` - a literal string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?P<username>\S+)` - Group  "username": one or more non-whitespace chars

Comment: Hello @Wiktor Stribiżew,
Sorry for poking around but I was wondering why this fails :
`RADIUS.*?Accounting[\s-]Request(?:.*?(Framed[\s-]IP[\s-]Address.*?Attribute.*?Value: (?P<client_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))?)?.*User-?[nN]ame[\s-]Attribute.*?Value:\s*(?P<username>\S+)`
i.e. why do we need another optional non-capturing group around `Value: 10.10.10.11` and not just capture client_ip as it is.

Comment: @tcpip Actually, I am not sure why I wrapped that part with an optional grouping, and in fact, `RADIUS.*?Accounting[\s-]Request(?:.*?(Framed[\s-]IP[\s-]Address.*?Attribute.*?Value: (?P<client_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)))?.*User-?[nN]ame[\s-]Attribute.*?Value:\s*(?P<username>\S+)` [works, too](https://regex101.com/r/HGxPzW/2). The point yours doesn't work is because you make only the group optional, but you need to wrap the group AND its right-hand `.*`/`.*?` with a non-capturing group in order to make the regex engine try that pattern at least once.